# Merging arrays, why is my input array mutated?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is what I'm trying to do :

I have these 2 arrays as inputs. I want to combine them, and merge the objects that have the same "type" property and for these, add the quantities.
So, with these 2 arrays below, I have an object with a "type" equal to veggie in each array. The resulting array would have an object with a "type" veggie, and the associated quantity equal to 30 (27+3).

```
const arr1 = [{"quantity": 27, "type": "veggie"}, {"quantity": 191, "type": "meat"}, {"quantity": 3, "type": "fruit"}];

const arr2 = [{"quantity": 13, "type": "fish"}, {"quantity": 191, "type": "dairy"}, {"quantity": 3, "type": "veggie"}];

const all = [...arr1, ...arr2];

function mergeArrays(arr) {
  const res = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    const findTagIndex = acc.findIndex((item) => item.type === curr.type);
    if (findTagIndex === -1) {
      acc.push(curr)
    } else {
      acc[findTagIndex].quantity += curr.quantity
    }
    return acc;
    }, []);

    return res;
}

const newArray = mergeArrays(all);
```

`console.log(newArray) // [{quantity: 191, type: "meat"}, {quantity: 30, type: "veggie"}, {quantity: 3, type: "fruit"}, {quantity: 13, type: "fish"}, {quantity: 191, type: "dairy"}];`

What I don't understand, and I'm stuck with, is that the merging of arrays seems to mutate `arr1`.
If I console log of `arr1` before and after getting the `newArray`, it will log resp. 27 and 30 veggies. What's going on ?

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong ? How else can I proceed ? I tried several things. I tried with a `forEach`. Same result.

Comment: `acc[findTagIndex].quantity += curr.quantity` changes the item in the array. Objects are not cloned when you transfer them, you just have physically *the same* objects but in two different arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You push the objects from the first array into the other array, thus both arrays hold *references* to the same objects. You can easily (shallow) copy the objects when pushing:

```
 acc.push({ ...curr });
```

Here's how I'd do that (in O(n)):

```
 const quantityByType = new Map();

 for(const { type, quantity } of [...arr1, ...arr2]) {
   amountByType.set(type, quantity + (quantityByType.get(type) || 0));
 }

 const result = [...quantityByType.entries()]
      .map(([type, quantity]) => ({ type, quantity }));
```

Comment: Assuming flat objects, then it's also just as easy to do `{...existingObj, quantity: existingObj.quantity + (quantityByType.get(type) || 0}}` to make a copy of the entire object. Easier than re-constructing them later, if you ever decide to add more properties.

Comment: You're my savior! Your solution is really nice! I love it. I did not think of Map() as I seldom see a use case for Map(). Thanks heaps for the explanation and the additional BigO comment!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `reduce` method to calculate sum:

```js
const arr1 = [{"quantity": 27, "type": "veggie"}, {"quantity": 191, "type": "meat"}, {"quantity": 3, "type": "fruit"}];

const arr2 = [{"quantity": 13, "type": "fish"}, {"quantity": 191, "type": "dairy"}, {"quantity": 3, "type": "veggie"}];

const merged = arr1.concat(arr2);

const result = merged.reduce((a, {type, quantity}) => {
    a[type] = a[type] || {type, quantity: 0};
    a[type].quantity += quantity || 0;
    return a;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```